# Perl GD does not draw circles, instead it draws a rectangle every time

Tags: image, perl, gd

I recently discovered the Perl module GD and I wanted to try it out a little bit.
So far I haven't got any problems creating a new object, allocating a color and redirecting the whole bunch of data into a file.
The problem came up as I opened the image file in a viewer:
No matter what I changed, it just displayed a rectangle. And to make fun of me it only got the right color (blue).

What is wrong? Is the creation of a circle not correct?

I will keep trying, but any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance for your help!

This is my code so far:

```
my $image1 = new GD::Image(100,100);
my $blue = $image1->colorAllocate(0,0,255);
$image1->arc(100,100,50,50,0,360,$blue);
my $print = $image1->png;

open(IMG,">","/home/bernd/perl/pie.png");
binmode IMG;
print IMG $print;
close(IMG);
```

Comment: Do you use `use strict; use warnings`? Maybe GD will tell you what's wrong. By the way: GLOB filehandles are outdated. You should use lexical filehandles. `open(my $fh,">","/home/..."`

Comment: Ok, thanks for the tip!
I just solved the problem, I just had to change the color of the circle. The first allocated color became the background (blue) and the circle used that color to, so nothing was visible.
I feel stupid now, but maybe this helps other beginners.

Comment: I know that feeling :D. Glad you got it working

Answer (score 2):

I believe the problem was that the background and foreground were the same color.

Here's a working example which draws a blue circle on a transparent
background:

```
use GD::Image;
use File::Slurp;

my $image1 = GD::Image->new(100,100);
my $white = $image1->colorAllocate(255,255,255);
my $blue = $image1->colorAllocate(0,0,255);
$image1->transparent($white);
$image1->interlaced('true');

$image1->arc(50,50,100,100,0,360,$blue);

write_file("/home/bernd/perl/pie.png", $image1->png);
```

I also updated the object creation to avoid using using the indirect
object notation style of `new GD::Image()` which is not recommended. `File::Slurp` was used to clean up writing out the file.

If you are new to image manipulation with Perl, I recommend that you
also check out Imager.pm, which has a more modern design.

Answer (score 0):

try adding :

```
my $image1 = new GD::Image(100,100);
my $white = $image1->colorAllocate(255,255,255);
my $blue = $image1->colorAllocate(0,0,255);
```

you are drawing the arc in the same color as your background

Comment: Thank you for your quick answers guys, but I solved the problem myself.
I feel stupid, for it's not obvious, but easy. No matter, now everything works fine (:

Thanks and have a nice day!